# How to hide the Mycustom button in tableView cell

Tags: iphone

I want to hide custom button present in tableview cell for a specific condition.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
     if(isDisplayMapbutton==YES)
   {                           
         UIView* buttonView1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
         mapBtn= [[MyCustomButton alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath];
         CGRect imageFrame1 = CGRectMake(0,2.0,30,30);  
         [buttonView1 setFrame: CGRectMake(230,3.0,30,30 ) ];
         [mapBtn setFrame:imageFrame1];
         [mapBtn setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Map.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [mapBtn addTarget:self  action:@selector(DisplayMap:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         [buttonView1 addSubview:mapBtn];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonView1];
         [buttonView1 release];

        [mapBtn release];
    }
    else        
    {

    }
  return cell;
}

-(void)toggleMove
  {
     if(isMove==YES)
     {
        isDisplayMapbutton  =NO;

        isMove=NO;
        //mapBtn.hidden=YES;
        [self getToolbar];
    }
    else
    {
        isDisplayMapbutton =YES;
     isMove=YES;
     //mapBtn.hidden=NO;

         [self getToolbar];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
}
```

If I use the above method  ,[self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
      the cell will be compressed. then map btn is moving to the end of cell. HOW to hide this Map
      button when we call the above method

Answer (score 1):

Right after you release `mapBtn`, do something like this

```
mapBtn = (MyCustomButton *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag: 1];
```

and also place this after the `mapBtn` method calls

```
mapBtn.tag = 1;
```

Comment: Good answer but you should explain what the tag is and how you are using it.

Comment: The tag is to distinguish this subview from the other ones. It's a simple way to obviously tell one from another.